# CucumberOptions and Runwith cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, maven-2, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMhGS.png)

Though I have followed all instructions given in youtube channels and google, still am getting the same issue.

I want to create a runner file, I have included all required dependencies in pom.xml,
Was getting warning:"Parameter "localRepository" is deprecated core expression; Avoid use of ArtifactRepository type. If you need access to local repository, switch to '${repositorySystemSession}' expression and get LRM from it instead.   While creating Maven project and Build is successful, does it going to affect anyhow?